# How do I change the name property of a <select> depending on which <option> is chosen in another <select>?

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I'm making a make/model form, with two  dropdowns. When a make is selected, the model dropdown with the appropriate list of models for that make is shown and the rest of the dropdowns for the other makes stay hidden. The problem I'm having is with posting the form to a text file. All of the fields post fine, except for the model field, which always posts the option selected in the last of the  dropdowns, which happens to be the list of Volvo models. I need to make the name="" attribute inside of  change to "car_model" for the active list of models.

Here's a short example of the code I have:

```
<tr>
    <td width="15%" class="label">Make:</td>
    <td class="inputd"><select id="makes" name="car_make" class="input">
        <option value="Default">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
        <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="15%" class="label">Model:</td>
    <td class="inputd"><div id="car_models">
        <div id="Default" style="display:block">
          <select name="car_model">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1">Choose Make First</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="Acura" style="display: none;">
          <select name="car_model">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="CL">CL</option>
            <option value="Integra">Integra</option>
            <option value="Legend">Legend</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="Audi" style="display: none;">
          <select name="car_model">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="A3">A3</option>
            <option value="A4">A4</option>
            <option value="A5">A5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="BMW" style="display: none;">
          <select name="car_model">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1 Series">1 Series</option>
            <option value="3 Series">3 Series</option>
            <option value="5 Series">5 Series</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the javascript I'm using to show/hide the divs:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#makes').change(function () {
        $('#car_models > div').hide();
        $('#car_models').find('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

I have the php form writing file writing the value from the  dropdown with the name "car_model", so I need to find a way to change that to a unique name when it is active.

Thanks.

Here's the code I'm using to write to the txt file:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$year = $_POST['car_year'];
$make = $_POST['car_make'];
$model = $_POST['car_model'];
$mileage = $_POST['car_mileage'];
$data = "$first_name, $last_name, $phone, $email, $zip, $year, $make, $model, $mileage
\n";
$fh = fopen("data.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
print "Thanks";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that all of your select lists have the same name and they are all submitted with the form, *even if they are not visible*. Since multiple variables with the same name get submitted, the last one always wins.

To fix this, disable the `<select>` elements in addition to hiding their containers:

```
$('#makes').change(function () {
    $('#car_models > div').hide();
    $('#car_models select').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#car_models').find('#' + $(this).val()).show()
                    .find('select').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, just changed out the code and it's still just working with the last select menu. It writes nothing for every brand other than Volvo.

Comment: @TrentMarshall: It works fine for me. Are you sure everything is in order? What does the receiving code look like?

Comment: Like it's working fine on the form, it's just the form writing to the text file that's giving me issues. Maybe it would be better if I changed the <select> names to be blank, and the script would add the "car_model" name to the active <select> dropdown. I just added the php scrip I'm using for writing to the question.